# Doing math calculations in a SQLite where clause

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

With Android's SQLite, is it possible to do math calculations on column values in a where clause? For example, say I want to select only the rows that have even values in their column named `mColumnName`. The following approach didn't work for me.

```
query(mTable, mColumns, mColumnName+"%2=?", new String[]{"0"}, null, null, null, null)
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android binds all query arguments as strings, which sometimes produces bugs when using functions and operations that produce numeric results. Inlining the zero in your selection string should fix this:

```
query(mTable, mColumns, mColumnName + " % 2 = 0", null, null, null, null, null)
```